# Text view text not wrapping properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to get my text to wrap underneath the top line on the left but it won't let me. I've even used `wrap_content`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/wc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/yellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/teal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/teal" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/red"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/and"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which text do you want to wrap is the "Terminus" or the big textview under?

Comment: The big text view under

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't use several textviews for that because several TextViews in a row gets align one after another  and you can't simple make the last one to go under if the text is to big. Use one TextView and by code  write your text with the help of html to get the several colors. Like This:

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view_id);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color="yellow">Way out,</font><font color="blue"> DLR,</font><font color="red"> Central</font>< color="white">  and Northern</font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of width and height used in a View ([API here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)).  First pair is measured width and measure height and determine how big a view wants to be in its parent.

But for your case to prevent text wrapping in a line you can use:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

This only works if all your text is in a single TextView.

If you are wanting an implementation that allows you to select individual entries maybe a better solution would be a ListView ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)) so that it is easier for the end user to navigate and select as well as easier to work with on the development side.

Or if you want to format the text for style, consider using a formatting technique within the single TextView.  Here is a [tutorial](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-1-5-how-to-color-part-of-the-text-and-use-alpha-channel-in-textview/) I found in a quick search.

Comment: Where it says 'Northern', I simply want that to go onto the next line since it is too long for the first.

Comment: yep, to avoid that break in Northern you would need to put it into a single TextView for the entire 'Way out, DLR, Central, and Northern' and use the formatting technique to apply color, fonts, etc. if you don't require them to be selectable.  Then use the android:inputType="text" to ensure proper text spacing so it doesn't split the word when it runs out of room in the view.